# Sort Bullets in Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `[datatype:varchar(50)]` in database (SQL Server 2008) having Values as shown below:

```
1
2
1.1.11
4.1
5
2.1
1.1
4
1.2.1
4.2.2
4.3
4.2
4.3.1
4.2.1
11.2
1.2.4
4.4
```

these are numbered bullets for my records 
I need to sort them as grouping all the records in sequence `1,1.1,1.1.1,2,3.1,4,10.1,11.1....`

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What about `order by column_name`?

Comment: Does `ORDER  BY CAST('/' + YourColumn + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)` do what you need?

Comment: AFAIK doing an `order by` on your column will sort them in ascending 'legal' heading type order. Do you need to concatenate all values into a single string as well?

Comment: @nonnb - That will put `11.2` before `2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly sorting dotted numbers stored as character in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446000/properly-sorting-dotted-numbers-stored-as-character-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
WITH T(YourColumn) AS
(
SELECT '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1.11' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '5' UNION ALL
SELECT '2.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '4' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.2.2' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.3' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.2' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.3.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.2.1' UNION ALL
SELECT '11.2' UNION ALL
SELECT '1.2.4' UNION ALL
SELECT '4.4'
)
SELECT *
FROM T 
ORDER BY CAST('/' + YourColumn + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)
```

Returns

```
YourColumn
----------
1
1.1
1.1.11
1.2.1
1.2.4
2
2.1
4
4.1
4.2
4.2.1
4.2.2
4.3
4.3.1
4.4
5
11.2
```

Is that what you need?