# Sql query to sort numbers & to get output as 1.1.1,1.1.2,1.1.3

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want sql query to get output as

`1.1.1,1.1.2,1.1.3...`

I tried order by clause but I am getting result as `1.1.1,1.1.10,1.1.11,1.1.2,1.1.3...`

My procedure is:

```
select * 
  from Projects,
 where iId in (select value 
                 from ParmsToList(@projectid,',')
              )
   And Projects.categoryid  > 0
 order by Projects.vProjectName
```

Comment: Pls Show your sample data in table Project, and describe table Project.  What is your RDMBS?

Comment: Wich RDBMS, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre? retag your question to get right answers

Comment: @UshmaRana Which version of SQL Server? If it's 2008 or later, try the answer to this question that was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12406985/1220971

Comment: 1.1.1 chaptera, 1.1.2 chapterb,....,1.1.10 chapterk

Comment: @UshmaRana, if your database is SQL Server 2005, delete your comment that says 2008.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to make them look like hierarchy nodes

```
;with t(f) as (
    select '1.1.1'  union
    select '1.1.10' union
    select '1.1.11' union
    select '1.1.2'  union
    select '1.1.3'
)
select
    *
from 
    t
order by
    cast('/' + replace(f, '.', '/') + '/' as hierarchyid)
```

for

```
f
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.10
1.1.11
```

Comment: i am getting error as Type hierarchyid is not a defined system type

Comment: The OP has now discovered thier database is MS SQl Server 2005.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008+:

```
select t.v
from (values ('1.1.1'), ('1.1.10'), ('1.1.11'), ('1.1.2'), ('1.1.3'), ('1.2.1'), ('10.1.1')) as t(v)
cross apply (
    select x = cast('<i>' + replace(v, '.', '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml)
) x
order by x.value('i[1]','int'),x.value('i[2]','int'), x.value('i[3]','int')
```

SQL Server 2005+:

```
;with t(v) as (
    select '1.1.1' union all 
    select '1.1.10' union all 
    select '1.1.11' union all 
    select '1.1.2' union all 
    select '1.1.3' union all 
    select '1.2.1' union all 
    select '10.1.1'
)
select t.v
from t
cross apply (
    select x = cast('<i>' + replace(v, '.', '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml)
) x
order by x.value('i[1]','int'),x.value('i[2]','int'), x.value('i[3]','int')
```

Output:

```
v
------
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.10
1.1.11
1.2.1
10.1.1
```

Comment: @UshmaRana it might be of more use to Denis if you could tell him what you mean by "not working" - do you get an error? Does it display results in the wrong order? Display nothing at all? Does the world end?

Comment: @UshmaRana which one? try the 2005 one

Comment: select * from Projects
cross apply (
    select Projects.vProjectName( cast('<i>' + replace(vProjectName, '.', '</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml))
) Projects.vProjectName 
 where iId in (select value from ParmsToList(@projectid,',')) And Projects.categoryid  > 0
order by Projects.vProjectName.value('i[1]','int'),x.value('i[2]','int'), x.value('i[3]','int')

Comment: above is ma query & m getting error as "Incorrect syntax near '.'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'And'."

Comment: @UshmaRana Now it's up to you how you use it in your environment. If you don't fully understand how it works, just play with it for several minutes. Like, outputing the categories and stuff. I have just shown how easy it is to parse a CSV list and interpret it to your needs.

Comment: @UshmaRana, you are not following Denis's solution. The way you will have to write the query is as follows....  SELECT * FROM (  SELECT * FROM Projects  ) AS tmpProjects  CROSS APPLY (  SELECT x = CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(vProjectName, '.', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS xml)  ) x  ORDER BY x.value('i[1]','int'),x.value('i[2]','int'), x.value('i[3]','int')

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY PATINDEX('%.%', [fieldname])
```

It worked for me