# Make build numbers sortable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

I have a series of build numbers which are stored as VARCHAR:

<kbd>**BUILDID**</kbd>   
<kbd>15.40.417</kbd>    
<kbd>16.40.11014</kbd>
<kbd>17.0.667</kbd>       
<kbd>17.0.700</kbd>       
<kbd>17.0.703</kbd>       
<kbd>17.0.710</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.137</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.141</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.142</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.151</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.167</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.211</kbd>       
<kbd>17.1.87</kbd>         
<kbd>**17.1.88**</kbd>         
<kbd>**17.10.12**</kbd>       
<kbd>17.20.7</kbd>         
<kbd>17.25.3</kbd>         
<kbd>17.25.5</kbd>         
<kbd>17.30.1</kbd>

We find the all too common problem of not using leading zeros when sorting.  I thought about splitting the numbers out and creating a BIGINT. Is there a better way to sort these?

Comment: Assuming this is rather like a "standard" version number, 256 * 256 * 256 * left number + 256 * 256 * middle number + right number gives you a 32 bit integer. Sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making this function:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Dan Andrews
-- Create date: 4/19/2017
-- Description: Converts Build IDs (17.20.1) to INTs (17020001)
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION fn_BuildID2INT(@buildID VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    @xml   XML
  , @value BIGINT = 10000000000
  , @total BIGINT = 0;
  SET @xml = CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@buildID , '.' , '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML);
  SELECT
    @total+=C.value('.' , 'int')*@value
  , @value/=100000
  FROM
    @xml.nodes('X') AS X(C);
  RETURN @total;
END;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON fn_BuildID2INT TO public;
```

Which gave me this:

<kbd>**Val**</kbd>           
<kbd>150004000417</kbd>
<kbd>160004011014</kbd>
<kbd>170000000667</kbd>
<kbd>170000000700</kbd>
<kbd>170000000703</kbd>
<kbd>170000000710</kbd>
<kbd>170000100137</kbd>
<kbd>170000100141</kbd>
<kbd>170000100142</kbd>
<kbd>170000100151</kbd>
<kbd>170000100167</kbd>
<kbd>170000100211</kbd>
<kbd>170000100087</kbd>
<kbd>170000100088</kbd>
<kbd>170001000012</kbd>
<kbd>170002000007</kbd>
<kbd>170002500003</kbd>
<kbd>170002500005</kbd>
<kbd>170003000001</kbd>

But... as [Martin Smith pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406985/sort-bullets-in-database), `ORDER BY CAST('/' + YourColumn + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)` is even better.