# Order by hierarchical substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I use SQL Server. I have columns in my table like so:

```
title:
1. Album one
2. Album two
2.1 - Song one
2.2 - Song two
2.10 - Song ten
```

I want to order my query by the first part of the string (the structure). If I order it now the result is the following:

```
select * from [albums] order by [albums].[title]

/* Result */

title:
1. Album one
2. Album two
2.1 - Song one
2.10 - Song ten /* notice this */
2.2 - Song two
```

How can I cast my string so I can order correctly?

Update:

I can have multiple/unknown levels of nesting (2.2.1.1, 2.2.1.2, 2.2.2, 2.2.3)

Comment: The biggest issue is that you have violated 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single tuple. That should be three columns instead of one (AlbumNum, TrackNum, Title). That being said you could likely convert the left portion of this to a numeric so you can sort it. My guess is though that your data is inconsistent and splitting this apart isn't going to be as simple as the data you posted here.

Comment: Also, the `.` in `2.10` (and the other numbers: `2.1`, `2.2`, etc) is **NOT** a simple decimal point. It is a _section separator_ between two distinct whole numbers. Therefore, casting to decimal will not (as you surmised) produce the correct results. You will need to parse out the values for each section separately. Again, this would be easier --MUCH easier, as well as perform much better -- if the data was actually stored in a normalized way.

Comment: you don't need to parse them out separately. If you have isolated the component (`2.2.3` or `2.2.2.1` etc) you can  [use hierarchyid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407095/73226) which is cumbersome but probably less so than alternatives

Comment: Totally forgot this even existed, probably the most sutable approach.

Answer (score 3):

One option is a CROSS APPLY to grab the desired portion of the string

```
Select [Title]
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( left([Title],charindex(' ',[Title])) ) ) B(Seq)
 Order by try_convert(int,parsename(Seq,2))
         ,try_convert(int,parsename(Seq,1))
```

**Results**

```
Title
1. Album one
2. Album two
2.1 - Song one
2.2 - Song two
2.10 - Song ten
```

**EDIT For multi Level**

```
Select [Title]
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values  ( try_convert(hierarchyid,'/'+replace(left([Title],charindex(' ',[Title])),'.','/')+'/' ))) B(Seq)
 Order by Seq
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can confirm that it works for simple cases like the one that I have posted. However, if my structure gets too complex (have unknown/multiple levels of nesting - i.e. 2.2.1, 2.2.1.2, 2.2.2.1) it does not work.

Comment: @stubborn See Edit for multi level

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SELECT *
FROM albums
ORDER BY HierarchyId::Parse('/' + 
                      TRIM ('.' FROM LEFT(title, CHARINDEX(' ', title)-1)) + 
                      '/')
```

This extracts the value before the first space as the value to sort, strips any trailing `.` from it (as is present in `1.` and `2.`) then uses the `HIERARCHYID` datatype to provide sorting with the semantics you desire.

([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8899a424e8e0e680b529ef982a9957d))