# Natural order by on period-delimited string in MSSQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've been working on producing a period-delimited hierarchy of integers that performs a 'natural' order by on a select query. I've had a go and the query below is touted as a solution for decimal ordering:

```
select id
from tablenm
order by
    case isnumeric(id + 'e0') 
        when 1 then 0 
        else 1 
    end,
    id
```

However, I'm not technically working with a decimal in all cases so I only have some limited success. Please note, there may be **multiple** levels in this hierarchy - I've only shown three in my example for brevity.

The SQL above produces the following output:

```
id
1
1.1
5
5.1
5.10
5.2
1.5.1
4.2.1
1.3.1
3.2.1
```

I need it to look like:

```
id
1
1.1
1.3.1
1.5.1
3.2.1
4.2.1
5
5.1
5.2
5.10
```

Thanks for any insight you're able to give.

Comment: Aren't the case conditions the same? And when they're both `1`, the results are different.

Comment: Also, what datatype are you using for column `path` ?

Comment: I've removed the extra case statement - bad copy. The column datatype is nvarchar.

Comment: This is [much easier in 2008+](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12406985/73226)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541020/638400

Note I can't take credit for this answer - the SQL is quite exceptional

Comment: Exactly what I needed - huge thanks. This appears to be really dynamic, dealing with alphabetic and numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final SQL for those who stumble upon the same dilemma:

```
declare @xml xml,
        @max_len int

set @xml =
(
    select  
        id
        ,cast('<i>' + replace(id,'.','</i><i>') + '</i>' as xml)
    from tablenm
    for xml path('id_root'), type
)    

select @max_len = max(len(x.i.value('.','nvarchar(10)')))
from @xml.nodes('/id_root/i') x(i)

select id 
from tablenm
cross apply(
    select 
        case 
            when isnumeric(x.i.value('.','nvarchar(10)')) = 1 
            then right(replicate('0',@max_len) + x.i.value('.','nvarchar(10)'),@max_len) 
            else x.i.value('.','nvarchar(10)') 
        end + '.'
    from @xml.nodes('/id_root/i') x(i)
    where x.i.value('../id[1]','nvarchar(50)') = tablenm.id
    for xml path('')
) as srt(srtvalue)
order by srt.srtvalue
```