# order sql server string like numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
I need to order string containing this format
```

> **number .(dot) number .(dot) number .(dot) number and so on multiple levels so the string can be**

1.1.1.1.1.1.5
or
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1......9
or 
5
or 
5.5.6.7.8.1.2.3454.2.11213

I have tried doing cast, but i need a solution other than common table expresions, because it is pretty slow.

is there a way to order this like numbers so 10 be next to 9 and not to 1, thank you

Comment: So these strings are not "numbers" per se, but are more akin to software version numbers?

Comment: What's the max number of digits per number?

Comment: You say you've tried a CTE with CAST; can we see that code?

Comment: What is your source of the data?

Comment: Is there a limit to the # of values in the string? I can think of a few ways to do it, but they're complicated. Can you use temp tables? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Related question has been addressed in following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446000/properly-sorting-dotted-numbers-stored-as-character-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, with a few assumptions, one being that the first digit always is an int.

```
insert into @t values ('1.0'),
('10.2.44.2'),
('5.2.523.242'),
('4.23.5511'),
('0.9.4343.1.6.2'),
('99.245.52371.0.1'),
('1.1.1.1.1.1.5'),
('1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1......9'),
('5.5'),
('5.5.6.7.8.1.2.3454.2.11213')

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(c, 0, COALESCE(CHARINDEX('.',c, 0), c)) AS INT) AS FirstDigit, c
from @t
order by FirstDigit
```

Results:

```
FirstDigit  c
0   0.9.4343.1.6.2
1   1.0
1   1.1.1.1.1.1.5
1   1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1......9
4   4.23.5511
5   5.2.523.242
5   5.5
5   5.5.6.7.8.1.2.3454.2.11213
10  10.2.44.2
99  99.245.52371.0.1
```

Comment: Lynn, I don't know - there isn't enough information in the question - those dots could have been ellipses, or part of the number. 

That one value seems different from the others. If the extra "." characters are removed, it appears in the list in the correct order. 

And assuming it is part of the number, there would need to be guidance to indicate how to sort a "." in comparison to a number - does it come before, or after?

Comment: In terms of alphanumeric sorting, I'd think you'd want to only the look at equivalent positions. In this case, the relevant text is "1.1.1.1.1.1.1" vs. "1.1.1.1.1.1.5". Not sure it matters that there are additional characters. But, like you said, the question does need more detail.

Comment: Right. There is a line in the question that states,

"number .(dot) number .(dot) number .(dot) number and so on multiple levels" which is what I based my answer on, and in those terms, it works.

Comment: sorry for the bad example out there, the 1.1.1.1.1...(this dots means it continues with the same patron numbers (dot) numbers (dot) for almost an infinite loop, like someone here says, it is more like a software version, but i have the problem here, with this numbers: `code` 1.10,1.1,1.11,1.11.1,1.1.10.9 i need to arrange it like a number the SQL you show in solution is not working with this case.