# Sorting hierarchical text in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy

I've a table with a `varchar` field. This field stores hierarchical numbers which I want to order.

Here is an example of my data:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3.
1.1.4
1.1.5
1.1.6.
1.1.7
10.
10.1
10.2
10.3
11.
11.1
11.2
2.
2.1
1.2.2
1.2.2.1
1.2.2.2
```

How can I achieve the following result with `T-SQL`:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.4
1.1.5
1.1.6
1.1.7
1.2.2
1.2.2.1
1.2.2.2
2.
2.1
10.
10.1
10.2
10.3
11.
11.1
11.2
```

I tried to split up the parts with the following SQL, but that's not elegant.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.',''))  = 0
  THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.','') 
  ELSE REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.',''),1, CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.',''))),'.','')
  END AS FIRST_PART
 ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.',''))  > 0
      THEN SUBSTRING( 
SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.','') 
   ,CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.','')) +1
   ,LEN( SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),1,LEN(NR)-1)+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(NR)),LEN(NR),1),'.','')  )
   )
  ELSE '0'
  END AS SECOND_PART
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

Is theree a better way to do this?

Comment: Store relations instead, instead of . separated items as column values?

Comment: I can only perform a SELECT and have no possibility to store relations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446000/properly-sorting-dotted-numbers-stored-as-character-in-sql-server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Value])
VALUES ('1')
      ,('1.1')
      ,('1.1.1')
      ,('1.1.2')
      ,('1.1.3.')
      ,('1.1.4')
      ,('1.1.5')
      ,('1.1.6.')
      ,('1.1.7')
      ,('10.')
      ,('10.1')
      ,('10.2')
      ,('10.3')
      ,('11.')
      ,('11.1')
      ,('11.2')
      ,('2.')
      ,('2.1')
      ,('1.2.2')
      ,('1.2.2.1')
      ,('1.2.2.2');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY CAST('/' + IIF(RIGHT([Value],1) = '.', LEFT([Value], LEN([Value]) - 1), [Value]) + '/' AS HIERARCHYID);
```

You can check the [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) for more details. The check in the `ORDER BY` clause is just removing the `.` at the end of the value (if such exist).

---

You can change the `IIF` function with simple `CASE WHEN` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY CAST('/' + CASE WHEN  RIGHT([Value],1) = '.' THEN LEFT([Value], LEN([Value]) - 1) ELSE [Value] END + '/' AS HIERARCHYID);
```

Comment: Works only with SQL Server 2012 and above. IIF isn't available at SQL Server 2008

Comment: @h0mebrewer You can easily change the `IIF` with `CASE WHEN` - check the edit.

Answer (score -1):

remove dots and order:

```
select column from table order by replace(column,'.','')
```

And there is no need to convert varchar to number if you want 10 to come before 2.

Comment: I don't want 10 for 2.