# Numeric sorting SQL server table by column starting with number and string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm going to sort an SQL server table by a column having following data:

```
2.5.1 Sonstiges
1.1.1 Pflegstandards
5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften
1.2.1 Anforderungen
2.4.5 Betriebsarzt
B Kernprozesse
1.1.1.4 Umgang mit
2.3.3 Kardiologie
......
```

as you see most of records begin with a number, but there are some starting with string as well. I use following query to cover both cases:

```
SELECT * from DocumentCategories 
  order by
    case IsNumeric(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','')) 
        when 0 then name
        when 1 then cast(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','') as int)
    end
```

But I get an error regarding varchar to int conversion (because of record containg "B Kernprozesse"). So what's the role of case/when here? Have I missed anything?

I want the output to look something like below:

```
B Kernprozesse
1.1.1 Pflegstandards
1.2.1 Anforderungen
2.3.3 Kardiologie
2.4.5 Betriebsarzt
2.5.1 Sonstiges
5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften
1.1.1.4 Umgang mit
```

......

Comment: Do not use `ISNUMERIC()` it has some issues. Does `B Kernprozesse` can be like `B Kernprozesse1.2.3`?

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a bad function, if I'm honest. If you *really* want to test if a string is a numerical value, use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Comment: Also, the problem here is that you are returning 2 different datatypes from your `CASE` expression. `[name]` is clearly a `varchar`, but your other expression is being cast to an `int`. As a result `[name]` is cast to an `int` as well, due to data type precendence and so the conversion fails.

Comment: What is your expected output? please add sample output data.

Comment: How does `1.1.1.4` compare to `1.1.2`? Right now, your replace turns this into `1114 vs 112`. Expected output would be helpful.

Comment: I've updated the question, and have mentioned what I expect.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446000/properly-sorting-dotted-numbers-stored-as-character-in-sql-server) question may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `TRY_CAST` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM @DocumentCategories 
  ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','') AS INT) IS NULL
        THEN 0 
        ELSE cast(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','') as int) 
    END
```

If you are in a SQL_SERVER enviornment prior to version 2012, you can use `ISNUMERIC` and get the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM @DocumentCategories 
  ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','')) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE cast(replace( LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)),'.','') as int) 
    END
```

Here are the results in both cases:

```
name
=====================
B Kernprozesse
1.1.1 Pflegstandards
1.2.1 Anforderungen
2.3.3 Kardiologie
2.4.5 Betriebsarzt
2.5.1 Sonstiges
5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften
1.1.1.4 Umgang mit
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I have a few more records starting with string? how can I have them sorted also? what does this 0 after then mean here?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet You can not easily sort numeric and alpha together. The 0 means if the `CASE` is true then use the provided value (0 in this case). 0 is used because it is lower than the other possible integers - If the `CASE` is true (name is not numeric / can not be cast), then put it at the top of the list. What this does is it assigns all non-numeric values to 0 and then the `ORDER BY` compares `0 and 0` and declares a tie. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: it is almost what I want, thanks for your descriptive comment :)

Comment: @Ali_dotNet I suggest opening a new question for your question here in the comments. I don't know if/how it's possible, but I'm sure there are other ideas out there how you can achieve that. You are trying to sort by alpha if the value is not numeric, but sort by numeric if the value is. Best of luck.

Comment: How does this sort values like `'1.12.123 Eins'` and `'11.21.22 Zwei'`?

Comment: @HABO His query replaces `.` with no-space so `112123` vs `112122`. `112122` would come first per his code he written. Similar situation where `1.1.1.4` is ordered to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      VALUES
      ('2.5.1 Sonstiges'),
      ('1.1.1 Pflegstandards'),
      ('5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften'),
      ('1.2.1 Anforderungen'),
      ('2.4.5 Betriebsarzt'),
      ('B Kernprozesse'),
      ('1.1.1.4 Umgang mit'),
      ('2.3.3 Kardiologie')
     ) T(Str)
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(LEFT(Str, 1) AS INT) IS NOT NULL
     THEN 0
     ELSE 1
END
```

Which will returns

```
+-----------------------------+
|             Str             |
+-----------------------------+
| 1.1.1 Pflegstandards        |
| 5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften |
| 1.2.1 Anforderungen         |
| 2.4.5 Betriebsarzt          |
| 2.3.3 Kardiologie           |
| 1.1.1.4 Umgang mit          |
| 2.5.1 Sonstiges             |
| B Kernprozesse              |
+-----------------------------+
```

---

UPDATE:

According to the last update of your question, you're looking for

```
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT *, ((LEN(Str) - LEN(REPLACE(Str, '.', ''))) * 2) + 1 N
  FROM (
        VALUES
        ('2.5.1 Sonstiges'),
        ('1.1.1 Pflegstandards'),
        ('5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften'),
        ('1.2.1 Anforderungen'),
        ('2.4.5 Betriebsarzt'),
        ('B Kernprozesse'),
        ('1.1.1.4 Umgang mit'),
        ('2.3.3 Kardiologie')
       ) T(Str)
)
SELECT *
FROM A
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(Str, N), '.', '') AS INT) IS NULL
              THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(Str, N), '.', '') AS INT)
         END
```

**Returns:**

```
+-----------------------------+---+
|             Str             | N |
+-----------------------------+---+
| B Kernprozesse              | 1 |
| 1.1.1 Pflegstandards        | 5 |
| 1.2.1 Anforderungen         | 5 |
| 2.3.3 Kardiologie           | 5 |
| 2.4.5 Betriebsarzt          | 5 |
| 2.5.1 Sonstiges             | 5 |
| 5.1.7 Arbeitsgemeinschaften | 5 |
| 1.1.1.4 Umgang mit          | 7 |
+-----------------------------+---+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b189562dbcab995f7889fe0266f36d36)**

Comment: As stated in updated question, 1.1.1.4 should be the last and 1.2.1 should come right after 1.1.1

Comment: @Ali_dotNet How do you determine if there is 3 nulbers? 5? 4? or it's static?

Comment: as you see in my query, I use replace in order to remove '.', in fact the number may be in the format 1, 1.1, 1.1.1 or 1.1.1.1

Comment: I think this query is removing the leading numbers (if exist at all) and then sorts by the resulting name, I want it to be sorted by numbers (of course after '.' are removed)

Comment: @Ali_dotNet Yup, I understand what you want to do and update the answer accordingly.